# Stop animation and start another with switch cases

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I have this animation that starts when its loaded:

```
<Grid.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent= "Canvas.Loaded">
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard x:Name="sb1" RepeatBehavior="Forever">
                    <DoubleAnimation Name="earth" From="0" To="-360" Duration="0:0:10" AutoReverse="False" Storyboard.TargetName="rotation" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Angle" />
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>           
    </Grid.Triggers>
```

how can i stop this and enter another event trigger with my switch cases, like mouseover.
I'm working with kinect audio source, so when the user says "america" or "europe" the animation should go and stop in that continent.

```
<EventTrigger RoutedEvent= ""><!--switch case "AMERICA" -->
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard x:Name="sb2">
                    <DoubleAnimation Name="america" To="0" Duration="0:0:5" AutoReverse="False" Storyboard.TargetName="rotation" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Angle" />
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
```

i have tried this, but doesn't work:

```
 switch (e.Result.Semantics.Value.ToString())
            {

                case "AMERICA":
                    americaSpan.Foreground = Brushes.DeepSkyBlue;
                    americaSpan.FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold;

                    Storyboard storyBoard1 = (Storyboard)FindName("sb1");
                    Storyboard storyBoard2 = (Storyboard)FindName("sb2");
                    storyBoard1.Stop();
                    storyBoard2.Begin();

                    break;   

            }
```

Comment: what's the error you get ? is FindName() returning null ?

Comment: It just doesn't work, the animation doesn't stop and the second animation doesn´t start. I need to stop first, and then when user enter a case trigger the second animation, but i don't know how to call it in the <EvenTrigger RoutedEvent= "">